# 4 Columns in 1 row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a bootstrap layout with 4 columns in 1 row but 1 column has to be under the right 2 columns.

Here is a screenshot of the end result I want:
[End result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W1Zl.jpg)

And here is what I do have right now:
[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c42lJ.png)

So the black column has to go to the right under the columns.

Here is the code I am using:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="home-teams">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: green; height: 500px;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: pink; height: 250px;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: yellow; height: 250px;">
                3
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: black; height: 250px; width: 50%;">
                4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Think you would need another row: https://www.bootply.com/0J51HxzHUd

Answer (score 2):

Use code as below(you can use bootstrap-4 spacing to sapces):

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/hm0z5od9/9/

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="home-teams">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: green; height: 500px;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row ml-md-1">
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: pink; height: 250px;">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 250px;">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-2 p-0">
                        <div style="background-color: black; height: 250px;">
                            4
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 1):

You should either nest two 2 column layouts:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">area 1<div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-6">area 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">area 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">area 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or abandon Bootstrap altogether and just style it with pure CSS using the `display:grid` property:

```
<div class="my-layout">
    <div id="area-1">area 1</div>
    <div id="area-2">area 2</div>
    <div id="area-3">area 3</div>
    <div id="area-4">area 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-layout {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 2em;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
#area-1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3 }
#area-2 { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3 }
#area-3 { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4 }
#area-4 { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<div class="home-teams">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="height: 500px;">

            <!-- Left side -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background-color: green; height: 500px;"> 1 </div>

            <!-- Right side -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

                <!-- Top Row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <!-- Left -->
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background-color: pink; height: 250px;"> 2 </div>
                        <!-- Right -->
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="background-color: yellow; height: 250px;"> 3 </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Bottom row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color: black; height: 250px; width: 50%;"> 4 </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: You do not necessarily require the row divs

Answer (score 0):

> "4 Columns in 1 row"

To keep them in a *single* row (which allows for re-ordering), disable the Bootstrap 4 flexbox, and simply use "floats" on `md` widths and larger...

```
<div class="home-teams">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row d-md-block">
            <div class="col-md-6 float-left" style="background-color: green; height: 500px;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 float-left" style="background-color: pink; height: 250px;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 float-left" style="background-color: yellow; height: 250px;">
                3
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 float-left" style="background-color: black; height: 250px; width: 50%;">
                4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/8Xc2ZsbCGS

Since `.d-md-block` is used on the `.row`, the layout will still use flexbox  on mobile devices.